# Dynamically Showing Articles Of The User Who Has Logged In?

Tags: articles, user, custom-module

I want to make a **custom page/module/iframe** or whatever which, when opened, will display only the **articles** written by the user WHO HAS LOGGED INTO MY JOOMLA WEBSITE. Is there any way to do that?

Suppose there are **two** users of my Joomla Website, **USER1** has written an article "ABC" and **USER2** has written an article "XYZ", I want to make a page which when opened by USER1 will only show "ABC" article and when opened by USER2, will only show "XYZ" article.

Is there a way out?

Comment: why? what is your goal? Maybe there is another way which is appropriate for your intention.

Comment: i let users write articles from my Joomla front-end but they are not permitted to publish them, first i review them & then i publish on my website. I want to make a page (only accessible to the registered users) which when opened will only show the published articles written by them! That's what i want to achieve, i want to add this page in the user menu.

Answer (score 3):

In the simplest form as you have described in your question, saying that you are just want to display content from the current user in a module, it is possible that some modules would have already such filter settings (that will use the current user id and retrieve/display their articles in the front-end). You can look in **[JED for article modules](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display)** and check for their features.

A module that provides plenty of filtering features, is the **[RAXO Pro](http://raxo.org)** module (commercial). It has an author filtering option to display : My articles or not my articles, that possibly might do the trick (but better ask a presale question).

If you won't find other modules, then you could customize a little the **Articles Category** module, that provides author filtering, and set it to use the current user id as the author.

Going deeper, you could create your own custom menu item for the com_content component and set up such filtering.

However, based on your comment above, I think that you are going to need a much more sophisticated solution, than a simple module or "iframe". There are various extensions that deal with the **front-end article submission/authoring**. Check the relevant [JED category](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content) to get some ideas.
I have seen extensions that deal exactly with this situation in the past, but I can't recall their names now.

Some other ideas would be to create your own content items with a CCK e.g **[K2](http://getk2.org/)**, or a custom app with an application builder like **[Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/)**, **[Seblod](http://www.seblod.com/)** or other similar tools.

**##UPDATE##**
To add some extra info, in the case you want to create your custom page, module, the key here is to use the current user id, as well as to check for the user access (probably users should be logged in, in order to submit articles or to see any unpublished articles).

To get the user id:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user->id;
```

Then you can display articles created by the user with this id.
Lastly, you should also set your desired viewing access level for that page/module (e.g. registered), so it will prompt user to login, before being able to see the content.

Comment: Woooo! That's alot of info. Thanks! Hope, it will help!